# What design pattern to apply for two different sets of classes which have exactly same usage

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing some code to consume two different versions of some api. Each of these versions are declared in versioned packages e.g., {v1.Connection, v1.query, v1.Result} and {v2.Connection, v2.query, v2.result} etc. The client code will be exactly identical except the classes are different. What design pattern can I apply here? I have no control on the api side.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: It cannot be Strategy, since I cannot make the original classes to inherit or implement from same super class(es).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is specifically a design pattern or a combination of design patterns (there are only a couple that I really know by heart these days, like state (machine), strategy and a few others), but using basic object-oriented design principles I would take an approach along these lines:

- Build an abstract layer above the v1 and v2 classes (a wrapper class (possibly abstract) or interface)
- Inject the v1 or v2 class into the wrapper class either through constructor injection or perhaps through a property in order to provide the actual implementation of the various methods etc.
- Use some sort of factory (or perhaps an IOC container) to control which version of the class(es) to inject.

That gives you the ability to add more versions in the future, to change them as needed and to leave your client code that relies on the abstraction less coupled to the underlying implementations.

Comment: So it seems that I don't have any other option except to create one class or interface for each class in versioned api. Your design makes sense.

Comment: Yes, at some level in the code you still need to reference the individual versioned api classes unfortunately. You can just abstract that portion away somewhere and have your client code talk to the more abstract layer so that only the version specific stuff needs to change as new versions are added etc.

Comment: I am recalling that this pattern has a name where you can have object or references of different types behind a wrapper and only one of those types is used at a time.

Comment: Yes there is probably a name for it and I used to be up on all that stuff. Lately I've been working in a non-object oriented language a lot, so OO design patterns have fallen out of my vocabulary and into the deep dark recesses of my brain :) Most design patterns are just a starting point for some "usual" approach to a given problem, but they all are really just an implementation of good OO design principles.